# Python: Null Output Instead of Correct Value

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function to add the digits of a given number repeatedly until I have a single digit.

So addDigits(345) = 12, 1+2 = 3, so this should return 3

Here's my attempt:

```
class Solution(object):
    def addDigits(self, num):
        """
        :type num: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        if (num >= 0 and num < 10):
            return num
        else:
            total = 0
            while (num >= 10):
                total += (num % 10)
                num /= 10
            total += num
            self.addDigits(total)
```

On input 10, I'm getting null back and I have no idea why.  I've traced through the code and it looks right to me...

Comment: You need to return the result of recursive call. `return self.addDigits(total)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach that splits your number into individual digits, and continuously sums them until you end up with a single digit.

```
total = 12348736

while len(str(total)) > 1:
    total = sum(map(int,str(total)))

print total
```

**EDIT**: Just to explain this further:

- `str(12348736)`: turns your number into a string
- `map(int, '12348736')`:
  turns your string (list of characters) into a list of integers (applies `int` to every character)
- `sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 7, 3, 6])`: adds up
  all the digits in the list

Comment: Omit the `list`: `sum(map(int, str(total)))`.

Answer (score 2):

The old technique of "casting out nines" gives a quick answer

```
def sumOfDigits(x):
    if x == 0: return 0 
    y = x % 9
    return 9 if y == 0 else y
```

An example shows why this works:

433 = 4*(99+1) +3*(9+1) +2 = 4*99 + 3*9 + (4+3+3)

reducing modulo 9 gives (4+3+3) (mod 9)

As Andrea's comment below points out, this gives the wrong answer when the sum of the digits is congruent to 9.

Comment: @Andrea Corbellini My mistake.  Let me see if I can correct it.